# Rails 4 remote request callback issue with data-type JS

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4

I'm having a issue on Rails 4.1.6, Ruby 2.3.0, JQuery 1.11.1 (jquery-rails 3.1.1, coffee-rails 4.0.1), I will make a simple example to explain my problem:

I have a view with a list of items that gets created with Ajax. On it, there is a button to create a new empty item, remotely:

```
button_to "Add Item",
          { action: :create },
          form: { id: "add_item_form" },
          remote: true
```

On my Javascript, I have hooked up the event:

```
$('#add_item_form').on('ajax:success', function (e, data){
  alert('Success!');
}
```

The controller:

```
def create
  @item = Item.new()
  @item.save!
  respond_to do |format|
    format.js
  end
end
```

Because the **create** method only responds to JS, it will attempt to render a JS view with the same name, which is fine:

create.js.erb

```
$('#item_list').append("<%= escape_javascript(render partial: 'item_li', locals: { item: @item }) %>")
```

And on the partial:

_item_li.html.erb

```
<li>
  <%= form_for(item, remote: true) do |f| %>
    // List of item fields from model
  <% end %>
</li>
```

If I run that code, it works fine, and the alert shows "Success!", the callback executes right after the partial view is rendered. The problem is, where that alert is, I would like to do some stuff with the information of the newly created Item (like the id), but I can't find a way to get the Item I created in the controller back at the callback function.

Since I'm working with CoffeeScript, my main javascript file, and create.js.erb can't communicate with each other (functions declared on main file can't be reached from the other file).

If I change my controller to do:

```
respond_to do |format|
  format.js
  format.json { render json: @item }
end
```

And change my data-type on the button to "json", I will get the item on the callback, but the partial view will never be reached. If I add both data-types, then I get whatever's on **create.js.erb** in the "data" variable on the callback.

What is the best solution to this problem?

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your problem correctly, you want to be able to do stuff with @item on the callback.

You should be able to manipulate @item from within `create.js.erb` instead of using the `success` callback.

To test this, I would remove this:

`$('#add_item_form').on('ajax:success', function (e, data){
  alert('Success!');
}`

and then add some Javascript code to your `create.js.erb` file:

```
$('#item_list').append("<%= escape_javascript(render partial: 'item_li', locals: { item: @item }) %>")
alert('Success!');
// Do whatever you want here, @item should be accessible
```

Comment: Yeah, this seems like it should work based on my understanding of the question. In addition, OP might try binding the functions in the 'main javascript file', or the Coffeescript file to the `window` object, so they're accessible anywhere.

Comment: This is my current workaround, but I wish I could get @item on the callback because I have several mayor functions on that file, and I don't want to repeat code

Comment: @NMPennypacker I want to avoid making the functions global, they are very specific to just that one view. Another workaround I thought of is adding a class "new" to the newly created item on "create.js.erb" and then finding it with $('li.new') on the callback, do what I have to do, and finally remove the "new" class. But I mean, there have to be a better way, right?

Comment: @GujMil Why not just put the relevant Javascript directly in your view file? I do it all the time.